# Null value replace android

Tags: android

The value null is coming. I want to replace the null value with no answer after I clear check.

```
     public void onFinish() {
        for (int i=0; i< rg.getChildCount();i++){
            rg.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false);
            rg.clearCheck();
        }
    }
}.start();  

btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        RadioButton uans=(RadioButton)findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

        String ansText = uans.getText().toString();
```

Comment: where you get null value?

Comment: If you are getting the null in uans(your question is not clear enough to tell me what exactly) , why don't you simply do a check for null and then assign ansText to "" if null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not enough info here to help you out with the error, but you simply can do this in order to get over this issue for now if uans variable is null :

```
String ansText;
if(uans !=null)
  ansText = uans.getText().toString();
else
  ansText = "No answer";
```